# issue with Vlookup in Pandas where key length is very large

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (df1 & df2). Both have 3 cols.

```
df1 = {'key' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'value' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        'commentary' : ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']}

df2 = {'key' : ['E', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C'],
    'value' : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'commentary' : ['pqr','stu','vwx','yzab','acad']}
```

Now I need to vlookup commentary col from df2 to df1. Hence df1 should look like below-

```
df1 = {'key' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'value' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'commentary' : ['vwx','stu','acad','yzab','pqr']}
```

PS: In my actual dataframes, the number of characters in key and commentary col is very large (aprrox 250 characters).

I am using below code; but is showing commentary col as 'blank'. Please correct me-

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

mapping_dict = dict(zip(df2['key'],df2['commentary']))
df1['commentary'] = df1['key'].map(mapping_dict)
```

Comment: How about a join? `res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='left')`

Comment: `df1['commentary'] = df1['key'].map(mapping_dict).fillna(df1['commentary'])`

Comment: The code in your question works as intended. Unless you can provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, it's impossible to help you.